# PushBackInputStream and DataInputStream, how to push back a double?

Tags: java, io, inputstream, datainputstream, pushbackinputstream

If I want to read ahead a byte,and push it back if it is not '<',I can do it like this:

```
PushbackInputStream pbin=new PushbackInputStream(new FileInputStream("1.dat"));
int b = pbin.read();
if(b!='<')
    pbin.unread(b);
```

But if I want to push back a double that I read from DataInputStream,what shall i do?
For example:

```
PushbackInputStream pbin1=null;
DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(
            pbin1=new PushbackInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream("1.dat")
                    )
        );
double d = din.readDouble();
pbin1.unread(d);
```

The last line `pbin1.unread(d);` can not be compiled,because the PushbackInputStream can not push back a double,how can I convent the double to byte array?or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't push back a double that way. Method `DataInputStream.readDouble()` reads 8 bytes to create a double, you can't just pass a double to `PushbackInputStream.unread()` and expect him to know how to deal with.

To achieve what you want the solution is simple:

```
PushbackInputStream pbin1=new PushbackInputStream(new FileInputStream("1.dat"));
DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(pbin1);

double d = din.readDouble(); // Get the double out of the stream
byte[] doubleAsBytes = new byte[8];
ByteBuffer.wrap(doubleAsBytes).putDouble(d); // transform the double into his byte representation
pbin1.unread(doubleAsBytes); // push back the bytes
```